# Laravel - Stripe - Ultrahook - Webhook are not caught

Tags: php, stripe-payments, laravel-5.4, webhooks, laravel-cashier

I'm using `Laravel 5.4` and `Laravel Cashier`. I would like to be able to catch `Stripe` webhooks in my `localhost:8888`

To do so I installed `ultrahook` and I started it like this

#### Ultrahook

`http://stripe.leococo.ultrahook.com -> http://localhost:8888/stripe/webhook`

#### Laravel routes

`Route::post('stripe/webhook', '\Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\WebhookController@handleWebhook');`

#### Stripe Webhook configuration

`http://stripe.leococo.ultrahook.com`

#### Problem

When I send a `webhook` from `Stripe` I get `Test webhook sent successfully`

In the terminal `ultrahook` I get this

`[2017-05-31 19:26:04] POST http://localhost:8888/stripe/webhook - 200`

But it seems the `handleWebhook` function is not triggered. It does not stop on a break point neither `die('test')`

I tried `php artisan route:clear` `php artisan config:clear`. I don't know wether it is normal or not, but I do not see anything in the `network` section in the Chrome Inspector

Comment: How are you determining it's not triggered? `die('test')` will result in a `200 OK` response to Stripe, so you'd still get the "test webhooks sent successfully". A Stripe webhook call would never show up in Chrome's inspector.

Comment: If I put a `xdebug` break point should it stop on it ? What is the right way to follow the execution of such a function ?

Comment: A breakpoint in your IDE isn't going to do much when your webserver gets the POST request. I'd use Laravel's `Log::debug()` function to output debug info to the logs in the `handleWebhook` function.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in your .env

```
CASHIER_ENV=testing
```

Laravel/Cashier checks if your call to the webhook has a valid event id.
To verify this, eventExistsOnStripe calls back stripe servers with this event id to check its existence.

Here is the main webhook entry point from Laravel/Cashier 7.0:

```
public function handleWebhook(Request $request)
{
    $payload = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    if (! $this->isInTestingEnvironment() && ! $this->eventExistsOnStripe($payload['id'])) {
        return;
    }

    $method = 'handle'.studly_case(str_replace('.', '_', $payload['type']));

    if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
        return $this->{$method}($payload);
    } else {
        return $this->missingMethod();
    }
}
```

isInTestingEnvironment just check whether we are in a testing environnment or not : Thank you Cpt Obvious :)

```
protected function isInTestingEnvironment()
{
    return getenv('CASHIER_ENV') === 'testing';
}
```